# Javascript regexp validation not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get my regexp working but I am not having much luck.

I would like to check whether the input string is 6 numbers and 1 character (123123A), no spaces, no dashes. My regex doesn't match even though I think I am entering a valid string.

Could anyone please point me where my issue is?

```
var userString = "123123A";
if( /^d{6}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/.test(userString) ){
  alert("Correct format");              
}
else{
  alert("Incorrect format");                    
}
```

Comment: What's the valid username you are typing?

Comment: put  the regexp on the input as a pattern attrib, which works without JS and helps AT.

Comment: @BustedSanta - I just edited your question to show you how to ask this sort of question in SO.  You want to give a really succinct working example, and keep your explanation centered around the actual problem you're having.

Comment: @smathy - thanks for the tip. I will try to do a better job describing my question the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, your regular expression syntax is incorrect, you want to use the token `\d` to match digits instead of matching the literal character `d` **six** times. You can also drop `{1}` from your character class, it is not necessary to use here.

```
if (/^\d{6}[a-zA-Z]$/.test(userString)) { ...
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. You answer has answered and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the value of the input element:

```
var userString = document.getElementById("username");
```

Should be

```
var userString = document.getElementById("username").value;
```

Also, like hwnd pointed out, you are missing the backslash in the pattern:

`/^\d{6}[a-zA-Z]$/`